# Swift: get assets from Photo Library with excluding subtypes

Tags: ios, swift, assets, phasset, photolibrary

I want to get list of assets from Photo Library but exclude subtypes or assets from smartfolders such as smartAlbumBursts, smartAlbumLivePhotos, smartAlbumScreenshots

my code is

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true) ]
options.predicate = predicate
let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: options)
```

I was trying to make predicate like that:

```
let predicateType = NSPredicate(format: "mediaSubtypes != %@", 
   PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoScreenshot as! CVarArg)
```

but 1. it crashes 2. i can add PHAssetMediaSubtype only for screenshot and livePhoto but not for burst photo.

I know that there is method

```
if let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, 
   subtype: .smartAlbumBursts, options: nil).firstObject {
```

but i am not sure how to use that metdhod or subtype  for my purposes

Was trying to use representsBurst but have a crash:

```
let predicateType = NSPredicate(format: "representsBurst == %@", NSNumber(value: false))
```

> reason: 'Unsupported predicate in fetch options: representsBurst == 0'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the table of [supported predicate and sort descriptor keys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phfetchoptions#overview) of **PHFetchOptions**.

I'd make an assumption that if an asset doesn't represent a burst then it doesn't have a burst identifier. You can combine it as you want:

```swift
let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true) ]

// fetch all images with no burstIdentifier
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "burstIdentifier == nil")
var assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: options)

// fetch all images with photoScreenshot media subtype
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "((mediaSubtype & %d) != 0)", PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoScreenshot.rawValue)
assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: options)

// fetch all images with photoLive media subtype
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "((mediaSubtype & %d) != 0)", PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoLive.rawValue)
assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: options)

// fetch all non-photoScreenshot and non-photoLive images
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (((mediaSubtype & %d) != 0) || ((mediaSubtype & %d) != 0))", PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoScreenshot.rawValue, PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoLive.rawValue)
assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: options)

// fetch all non-photoScreenshot and non-photoLive images with no burstIdentifier
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (((mediaSubtype & %d) != 0) || ((mediaSubtype & %d) != 0)) && burstIdentifier == nil", PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoScreenshot.rawValue, PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoLive.rawValue)
assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: options)
```

Answer (score 0):

NSPredicate is tricky. The way to say "not" is like this:

```
NSPredicate(
    format: "!((assetCollectionSubtype & %d) == %d)",
        PHAssetCollectionSubtype.smartAlbumBursts.rawValue)
```